# Performance impact of querying SQL server DMVs

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, dmv

Is there any performance impact on a busy production SQL Server 2008 when I query DMVs such as sys.dm_exec_query_stats, sys.dm_tran_locks, or sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Each one has a different impact. The impact depends on how many entries are returned (which often implies how many internal data structures have to be traversed) and some DMvs are inherently more performance sensitive than others (eg. `sys.dm_tran_locks` will have bigger impact that `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` simply because the lock data structures are so much hotter than the query cache). Some DMvs like `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats` imply on-disk data scans and they will be *extreamly* expensive, comparable to a full table scan.